# How to set size of mate-panel via command line (not via dconf)?

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, mate-desktop, dconf

When I install Linux Mint (Mate, Qiana) I like to make Mate panel more wide (or may be "higher"). 
Default it is near 20 pixels. I make it, for example, 45 pixels. I can easy set it by right button click mouse on the panel.

Now I want to make file with all my preferences that I use to install in Linux. There will be **commands for Terminal** (command line). And I need help with mate-panel settings.

I found that I can set size of mate-panel in dconf editor:
*org - mate - panel - toplevels - bottom*
size 45

**Question: How to make the same in command line?**

**NB!** This *"size"* is not simple value. Perhaps it is part of list of values. I can see in dconf in "org - mate - panel - general" value *toplevel-id-list* is equal *'bottom'*. Its description is:

*"A list of panel IDs. Each ID identifies an individual toplevel panel. The settings for each of these panels are stored in /apps/panel/toplevels/$(id)".*

So must I to edit this *list*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a MATE environment to test on but in general, this type of thing can be set using `gsettings`. Try this:

```
gsettings set org.mate.panel.toplevel:/org/mate/panel/toplevels/bottom/ size 45
```

That should set the value you want. For more details, see http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/docs:gsettings.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is right idea. And... eureka!! :-)

I have red the manual. Right command is exactly:

`gsettings set org.mate.panel.toplevel:/org/mate/panel/toplevels/bottom/ size 45`

Comment: Sorry, I can not press here "This answer is useful" (something like "Like" :-)), because I must have reputation > 15 for this.

Comment: @Andrey don't worry about it, you already did the most important thing which is accepting. That is the equivalent of marking a question as "SOLVED".

Comment: gsettings indeed seems to be the most current, most correct choice as of 2020, even if other answers suggest a working alternative. In case you get some confusing answers regarding dconf vs gsettings while researching this (as I did):  https://people.gnome.org/~pmkovar/system-admin-guide/gsettings-dconf.html